# Breakpoints are ignored when debugging in Visual Studio 2008 on 64-bit system

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, 64-bit

I'm trying to debug an ASP.NET web application in this environment:

- Windows Server Standard 2008 SP2 **x64**
- **Single-core** CPU
- 4GB RAM
- Visual Studio 2008 with Remote Debugger SP1
- .NET 3.5 Web Application running in IIS in 64-bit mode

The code I am trying to debug is a simple event handler with some basic sequential code.
What I observe is that breakpoints get randomly ignored and VS often exits debug mode when I try to step through the code.
The code is **compiled in debug mode**.

EventViewer shows no warning or error messages that would relate to this. I am certain that this is not caused by IIS app pool recycle/reset.

I've tried all the usual steps: iisreset, reboot VM, rebuild solution, reinstall Visual Studio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find a solution.

Worked around this behaviour by using a combination of [Debug.Print()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9azyssyh.aspx) and [Sysnternals DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Windows Form application, and I applied the same hotfix as Julien did. (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912). I haven't had the problem since.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your IIS App Pool is recycling for some reason once in a while. This kills the IIS worker process and therefore unhooks the debugger.

You can check if this happening in the Eventlog. Also check you application pool settings in IIS Manager.

Comment: EventViewer shows no warning or error messages that would relate to this. I am certain that this is not caused by IIS app pool recycle/reset.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with randomly missed breakpoints and debug mode resuming/stopping when stepping through, on a WPF application though. This fix solved it:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912